# ScrollView -> ChildView not sizing to constraint

Tags: ios, swift

I have created AutoLayoutConstraint as per the screenshot, following a tutorial on [youtube](https://youtu.be/b8eyR_jBIpE).  It works well except the ChildView (green) does not stretch to fill the width of the screen.  The childView width seems to stay at 320. How can I make the childView stretch in width so that it fills the width of the screen/scrollView(blue)?

Any help would be very much appreciated!  Thank you.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Document Outline view, control-drag from the childView to the scrollView and select Equal Widths from the pop-up.

Comment: Thank you - that works perfectly!!  So strange that zero leading and trailing distance to superView does not work.

Comment: Zero leading and trailing distance doesn't work because you need something to say how big the scollView content is.  You did this for your height by setting it explicitly to 800.  For the width, you need to either set it equal to something outside of the scrollView content, or fully constrain objects of fixed size within the scrollView content.  Zero leading and trailing provides no information to Auto Layout about how wide to make the view.